# How to play video file in AVPlayer outside of app bundle

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, avkit

How do I play a video file which is not included in my app bundle?
I am able to play videos within my app bundle

```
    @IBOutlet weak var playerView: AVPlayerView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let videoUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "captionsSample",  withExtension: "mp4")!
    let item = AVPlayerItem(url: videoUrl)
    let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)
    playerView.player = player
}
```

But when I try to play from desktop or some other location, AVPlayer wont play it.

I would like to build a video player which plays a video file as soon as it gets clicked.

I also checked the Apple tutorial, but it only demonstrates how to play videos at the remote location.

Comment: It depends on the sandbox. If the app is sandboxed the file must be located in the application container (which is different from the bundle).

Answer (score 0):

As @vadian suggested, the issue was that my application was sandboxed. If you turn off sandboxing you will be able to read/write any file outside of app bundle. This may seam like a convenient solution, but is not recommended. The recommended way would be to leave the sanboxing turned on and add the needed permissions to your entitlements file.